# How many $4$ digit numbers can be formed using $0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3$?

Tags: combinatorics

I've solved forming $8$ digit number using $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3$. We have 8 digits: two 1, three 2 and three 3. First I put three 2's in 8 possible places. Number of putting 2's is $\frac{8!}{3!5!}$ . After putting 2's we have 5 possible empty places left. We put three 3's: $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ . Then we have 2 empty places and two 1's: $= \frac{2!}{0!2!} $. The answer will be multiplication of all these.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sum of multinomial coefficients

$$\frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{2}\sum_{h=0}^{2}\binom{4}{4-j-h,j,h}$$

The fraction is to discount the strings that start with zero.

P.D.: this answer is related to the title, not the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The total ways are $8!/4!.2!.2!- (1.7.6.5+1.1.6.5.3)=120$ 0 cannot be in thousands place but there are numbers where 0 is constant at thousandth place and second zero is changing the places. I have multiplied by 3 as 2 nd 0 can be unit ,tenth,hundreth place . Thus the answer is 120.

Comment: Note the answer is for the title.